# How to modify a dataset to make a unique dataset in matlab

Tags: matlab, unique, noise

I have a matrix `M` in MATLAB, containing `m x n` numbers. I want to add very small noises to repeated rows to make it unique, i.e., `size(M,1) = size(unique(M,'rows'),1)`.

**EDIT**:
I have tried this. But it is not deterministic.

```
while size(unique(allDataUnnormalized,'rows'),1)~=size(allDataUnnormalized,1)
    [~, tmpDist] = knnsearch (allDataUnnormalized,allDataUnnormalized,'k',2);
    importantIdx = find(tmpDist(:,2)==0);

    allDataUnnormalized(importantIdx,:)=allDataUnnormalized(importantIdx,:)+rand(numel(importantIdx),NDims)*epsilon^4;
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding noise is cheap, why wont you just try something like:

```
 allDataUnnormalized = allDataUnnormalized + eps*rand(size(allDataUnnormalized));
```